# How to flash stock rom with Jodin3 on linux?

Tags: linux, rom

I tried to flash stock rom for Samsung Galaxy j3 2016(320FN) with Jodin3 Casual under Linux Mint and i get this error:

```
  Initialising protocol...
  Failed to send data!Releasing device interface...
```

What should i do?I don't have a windows machine to use Odin.

Comment: you can flash with heimdall https://android.stackexchange.com/q/44106

Comment: The thing is that i wanted to do this when the display was working,now i just want to cast it to pc.

Comment: I tried again to flash the phone,it doesn't gave me that errror but now when i press start it doesn't start .The led from unity is red for a couple of seconds,it says "running" but it doesn't do anything.I tried to change the firmware from tar.md5 to tar but nothing.Any suggestions? The thing is that i've flashed a twrp recovery for this phone with Jodin3 but why it dosen't work with the stock firmware?

Comment: I will flash the stock recovery and then flash the stock rom but i think it will not work because i tried with another Samsung and it didn't work.This phone(SG J3)has the display broken.Sorry i'm not that good at this.Anyway...thank you.

Comment: I flashed stock recovery but with stock rom will not work.Idk

Comment: flash another [rom](https://www.xda-developers.com/samloader-download-updates-samsung-galaxy) that work

Comment: I have 3 rom versions on my pc.None of them work

Comment: How do you know without screen?

Comment: I have another Samsung phone that works and it does the same...i press start after i obtain the pit file and it says running and it doesn't do anything.With SGJ3 i do everthing in my mind,with my imagination :).I have to ask you.The md5 file have to be in PDA section right?

Comment: Which one? There should be 4 files
https://android.stackexchange.com/a/193949

Comment: I tried with the 4 firmware files but it gave me an error saying that it has a corrupt file.I mean the firmware file has to be in PDA section.

Comment: I think i'd better use heimdall-frontend but i don't realy know were to put those files(system.img recovery.img and so)

Comment: Over wine it doesn't work.Maybe i will try it with windows.Thank you for your time.

Comment: [combination](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232270/why-i-get-permission-denied-on-adb-on-android-phone#comment306145_232270) firmware only works on same bootloader [level](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/180313) maybe the issue is with downgrade?

Comment: Idk,maybe.The fact is that i tried to flash it via heimdall but i get protocol initialization failed...and i think i did everything correctly.

Comment: *"protocol initialization failed"* is a common error if not using latest heimdall v1.4.2 for JOdin3/heimdall frontend

Comment: i've installed heimdall v1.4.2 and i get the same error.Jodin3 gives me this eror when i try to install drivers:"dpkg: regarding .../heimdall_amd64.deb containing heimdall:
 heimdall-flash conflicts with heimdall
  heimdall (version 1.4.0-0) is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/CASUALenq-2021-07-12-15.09.14/heimdall_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing heimdall
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/CASUALenq-2021-07-12-15.09.14/heimdall_amd64.deb"

Comment: Man,i give up.I will try to flash it with Odin and maybe in the future i will find a solution for heimdall.
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Hey! I've managed to flash it with heimdall-frontend.What it did was to pull out the battery and reboot into download mode without the Usb cable plugged in and then i plugged in the usb cable and pressed start and the flash was succesfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To flash the latest Firmware via Jodin3** download stock ROM according to your CSC region/carrier.

unpack four (4x) `tar.md5` files, for example

```
BL_J320FNXXU0ARH1_CL13891268_QB19182728_REV00_user_low_ship.tar.md5
AP_J320FNXXU0ARH1_CL13891268_QB19182728_REV00_user_low_ship.tar.md5
CP_J320FNXXU0ASF2_CL491657_QB13009723_REV00.tar.md5
CSC_BTU_J320FNBTU0ARH1_CL13891268_QB19182728_REV00_user_low_ship.tar.md5
```

open JOdin3 and **un**tick all checkboxes like auto-reboot, re-partition etc.

assign the files according to it's prefixes

```
BL   Bootloader   BL_J320FNXXU0ARH1_CL13891268_QB19182728_REV00_user_low_ship.tar.md5
AP   PDA          AP_J320FNXXU0ARH1_CL13891268_QB19182728_REV00_user_low_ship.tar.md5
CP   PHONE        CP_J320FNXXU0ASF2_CL491657_QB13009723_REV00.tar.md5
CSC  HOME_CSC     CSC_BTU_J320FNBTU0ARH1_CL13891268_QB19182728_REV00_user_low_ship.tar.md5
```

connect device in download mode (Volume Down + Power)

click `Start` to begin the flashing process. wait up to 7-10 minutes until you see `PASS!` message. Don’t unplug the device.

Be aware flashing will **factory reset** your device!

---

**Another approach is flash partitions with heimdall** command line manually. this way you ensure userdata partition is not wiped during flash (no factory reset)

use **p7zip** to extract all `tar.md5` files

```
7z x <file>
```

in `CSC_*.tar.md5` find the `J3XNLTE_*.pit` file which contains all file names and partition names.

open the `.pit` file with hex editor. check the extracted file names and use the previous word as partition name

```
0x00000C00   14 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 70 02 00   .............p..
0x00000C10   00 A0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 4B 45 52 4E   . ..........KERN
0x00000C20   45 4C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   EL..............
0x00000C30   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 62 6F 6F 74   ............boot
0x00000C40   2E 69 6D 67 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   .img............
0x00000C50   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0x00000C60   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0x00000C70   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0x00000C80   02 00 00 00 15 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00   ................
0x00000C90   00 10 03 00 00 A0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ..... ..........
0x00000CA0   52 45 43 4F 56 45 52 59 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   RECOVERY........
0x00000CB0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0x00000CC0   72 65 63 6F 76 65 72 79 2E 69 6D 67 00 00 00 00   recovery.img....
0x00000CD0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
```

flash all partition images (except userdata.img) via **heimdall command line**, for example

```
heimdall flash --BOOT spl.img --BOOT2 spl2.img --MD5HDR md5.img --SBOOT sboot.bin --SBOOT2 sboot2.bin --l_fixnv1 nvitem1.bin --l_fixnv2 nvitem.bin --pm_sys PM_sharkl_arm7.bin --l_ldsp SPRDLTEDSP.img --l_modem SPRDCP.img --l_gdsp SPRDGDSP.img --l_warm SPRDWDSP.img --PARAM param.lfs --efs efs.img --prodnv prodnv.img --KERNEL boot.img --RECOVERY recovery.img --PERSDATA persdata.img --CACHE cache.img --SYSTEM system.img --HIDDEN hidden.img
```

Comment: With Jodin3 i get an error saying i have i corrupted file from those 4 firmware files and with haimdall i use heimdall-frontend saying after i press start "protocol initialization failed".Those 4 firmware files i make them from stock rom with Samsung Firmware Maker and maybe that's why i get corrupted file.Heimdall i can't use it manually because i'm not that good at this and i'm afarid to brick the device.